# Winding Factor in Single Phase Induction Motors

Tags: motor, ac, induction-motor, electric-machine

How does one compute the winding factor in a Single Phase Induction Motor? I have checked Wikipedia, but it only states the relevant formulae for three-phase machines with no explanation of the theory.

Here's an excerpt from the book "Induction Motors" by Amin:

[image]

What exactly is M1? There is no previous mention of it anywhere in the book...is it an empirical coefficient of some sort, and where do I look it up?

According to this book the winding factor is defined as the square root of the ratio of the flux linkage of a distributed winding to that of a concentrated winding.

What surface do we use to compute the flux-linkage, or is it arbitrary? I also need to know the geometry of the current source to determine the magnetic field, what geometry do we assume?

Could someone explain concretely how do we obtain the value of the winding factor, preferably within the context of Capacitor Run SPIMs?

Sorry for my ignorance, I come from a pure physics background...